# Injecting Collection of Lazy using Castle Windsor

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I created this interface:

```
public interface IGate
{
  string Name { get; }
  void Send();
}
```

In runtime i need to choose from multiple implementation of this interface the one that relevant for me (according to data i will get inside my WCF request).

Because I'm using Castle Windsor as my DI container in this project
i did something like that:

```
    public class GateFactory : IGateFactory
    {
       private IList<IGate> _list;
       public GateFactory(IList<IGate> listOfGates)
       {
          _list = listOfGates;
       }

       public IGate Create(string name)
       {
          return _list.First(o => o.Name == name);
       }
    }
```

So inside my code i am using the IGateFactory to create the appropriate IGate (again according to the name i will have at runtime).

i used `container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new CollectionResolver(container.Kernel));` to resolve the collection
in my configuration code

the problem is that i dont want to instantiate all the Gates in my system when i know i will use only one of them (i will have something like 30 Gates).

i thought to inject `IList<Lazy<IGate>>` but when i run on the list to check the name for each one i will practically instantiate each one of them and that is exactly what i wanted to avoid.

Another solution will be to inject something like `IDictionary<string,Lazy<IGate>>`   but i dont know how to configure that
(using code)

**also note that i need the collection (may it be list or dictionary) to be new (LifeStyle.Transient) every time we get the GateFactory**

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [Typed Component Selector](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#custom-itypedfactorycomponentselectors). Why this? Because of your statement

> In runtime i need to choose from multiple implementation of this interface the one that relevant for me

Probably the question should be "How to choose from multiple implementations at runtime according to a parameter?"

When you have to choose from already made implementations - go for **Component Selector** (read it in the sense of a **Component Selector Factory Pattern** rather than name of the implementation) - the guy who selects the right component at runtime.

When you have to create something at runtime out of *params* like a connection or something else which does not exists prior to the call - go for a factory method or another thing that creates *new* stuff at runtime.

An [excerpt](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#custom-itypedfactorycomponentselectors) for your case :

```
public class CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector : DefaultTypedFactoryComponentSelector
{
    protected override string GetComponentName(MethodInfo method, object[] arguments)
    {
        if (method.Name == "GetById" && arguments.Length == 1 && arguments[0] is string)
        {
            return (string)arguments[0];
        }
        return base.GetComponentName(method, arguments);
    }
}

// somewhere in your registration ....
var ioc = new WindsorContainer();
ioc.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();
ioc.Register(Component.For<ITypedFactoryComponentSelector>().ImplementedBy<CustomTypedFactoryComponentSelector>());
```

Start reading from [here](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/typed-factory-facility-interface-based.md#resolving-with-arguments).

For the *Lazy* part - it will be selected and instantiated runtime. Register your component as transient so every time there is a new implementation. By doing it like that you will get as lazy as possible because the instances will be created at the last possible moment and will be disposed as you like.

This is the explanation of [how castle windsor tracks components](http://kozmic.net/2010/08/19/must-windsor-track-my-components/).

Comment: Thanks! this really help

Comment: although Castle windsor provide the TypedFactoryFacility to solve the problem with resolving object when we only know which dependency we will need in runtime you can acheive the same result without all this overhead according to this post http://mikehadlow.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/10-advanced-windsor-tricks-1.html

but i think it will work only if your instances dont take dependencies